# memory analysis from eclipse ide does not list any local process id when acquire heap dump dialog is clicked

Tags: java, eclipse, heap-dump, jmap

Using memory analyzer from eclipse ide (kepler), I'm trying to acquire  heap dump from a locally running VM while an program is running, however acquire heap dump dialog does not list any pid to select.
I try to configure hdrof jmap dump provider

with

-jdkhome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

but nothing happens.
Any solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

remove bin from your path , It should be -jdkhome C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05