# Java: Eclipse: Memory Analyzer: Acquire Heap Dump Dialog shows no PID to acquire

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I'm using Eclipse for a Java project and I suspect a memory leak.

I'm trying to use a memory analyzer for the first time since my project used to be simple enough.

I downloaded the Memory Analyzer from Eclipse marketplace, restarted it, launched my application and clicked on "Acquire Heap Dump Dialog".

But **the list of process remains empty in the Acquire Heap Dump Dialog window** even after refreshing, choosing a heap dump provider in Configure or relaunching the app.

[image: No process to acquire]

What am I missing here?

**Nota**: I saw [memory analysis from eclipse ide does not list any local process id when acquire heap dump dialog is clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433668/memory-analysis-from-eclipse-ide-does-not-list-any-local-process-id-when-acquire) but the answer is not validated and I think if the path wasn't good, the app wouldn't launch. (Am I even correct on this?)

Comment: Which JRE/JDK versions do you have installed? The Heap Dump Dialog may not work with all JVM vendors/versions. From the docs: `Acquiring the heap dump is VM specific. Memory Analyzer comes with several so called heap dump providers - for Oracle and Sun based VMs (needs a Oracle or Sun JDK with jmap) and for IBM VMs (needs an IBM JDK or JRE). Also extension points are provided for adopters to plug-in their own heap dump providers.`

Comment: @Robert The JDK is 1.8.0_161. 
So what I understand is that I should install another tweaked version of Java, let's say IBM specific, and then choosing IBM Dump on the configure menu will work?
If so, I should be able to find it on Oracle website? Or IBM's maybe?